# How to make google login certificate verification with jwt in php lighter?

Tags: php, jwt, google-api-php-client

I'm following all the steps to verify the Google Authentication api login according to the documentation in the link below:

https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/verify-google-id-token

And according to the documentation, it says to use the Google APIs Client Library for PHP

https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client

But this library in composer loads more than 20 thousand files. And my server has a limit of inodes (amount of files that can exist on the hosting) So I think it would be too heavy to for check the login certificate token.

And then in the library I saw that there is a line to clean up unused services with `Google\Task\Composer::cleanup` by putting the following lines in composer:

```
{
    "require": {
        "google/apiclient": "^2.12.1"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "pre-autoload-dump": "Google\\Task\\Composer::cleanup"
    },
    "extra": {
        "google/apiclient-services": [
            "Drive",
            "YouTube"
        ]
    }
}
```

But I'm not going to use any of the services other than the auth token verification. How should I put these lines?

I also thought about not using any of that and just putting `firebase/php-jwt` in the composer and trying to recreate the library's **Verify.php** file

https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/ea2d79cc006ed19dc7a148792b978bc16d1622d1/src/AccessToken/Verify.php

But I still don't know how to do it, it seems that a file always depends on other files and then the composer ends up still loading hundreds of useless files.

I've been trying to do this for days, and I can't find any solution that doesn't need to load so many files. Does anyone know how to do this more directly, with only what is really needed?

This is the file I'm trying to rebuild, but everything is still weird and I'm not understanding if I'm on the right path.

```
<?php

namespace FVRCmds;

use Firebase\JWT\ExpiredException as ExpiredExceptionV3;
use Firebase\JWT\Key;
use Firebase\JWT\SignatureInvalidException;

class FVRJWT {
    const FEDERATED_SIGNON_CERT_URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs';
    const OAUTH2_ISSUER = 'accounts.google.com';
    const OAUTH2_ISSUER_HTTPS = 'https://accounts.google.com';

    /**
     * @var \Firebase\JWT\JWT
    */
    public $jwt;

    /**
     * Instantiates the class, but does not initiate the login flow, leaving it
     * to the discretion of the caller.
     */
    public function __construct($jwt = null) {
        $this->jwt = $jwt ?: $this->getJwtService();
    }

    /**
     * Verifies an id token and returns the authenticated apiLoginTicket.
     * Throws an exception if the id token is not valid.
     * The audience parameter can be used to control which id tokens are
     * accepted.  By default, the id token must have been issued to this OAuth2 client.
     *
     * @param string $idToken the ID token in JWT format
     * @param string $audience Optional. The audience to verify against JWt "aud"
     * @return array|false the token payload, if successful
     */
    public function verifyIdToken($idToken, $audience = null)
    {
        if (empty($idToken)) {
            throw new LogicException('id_token cannot be null');
        }

        // set phpseclib constants if applicable
        $this->setPhpsecConstants();

        // Check signature
        $certs = $this->getFederatedSignOnCerts();
        foreach ($certs as $cert) {
            try {
                $args = [$idToken];
                $publicKey = $this->getPublicKey($cert);
                if (class_exists(Key::class)) {
                    $args[] = new Key($publicKey, 'RS256');
                } else {
                    $args[] = $publicKey;
                    $args[] = ['RS256'];
                }
                $payload = \call_user_func_array([$this->jwt, 'decode'], $args);

                if (property_exists($payload, 'aud')) {
                    if ($audience && $payload->aud != $audience) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                // support HTTP and HTTPS issuers
                // @see https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth
                $issuers = [self::OAUTH2_ISSUER, self::OAUTH2_ISSUER_HTTPS];
                if (!isset($payload->iss) || !in_array($payload->iss, $issuers)) {
                    return false;
                }

                return (array) $payload;
            } catch (ExpiredException $e) { // @phpstan-ignore-line
                return false;
            } catch (ExpiredExceptionV3 $e) {
                return false;
            } catch (SignatureInvalidException $e) {
                // continue
            } catch (DomainException $e) {
                // continue
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private function getCache()
    {
        return $this->cache;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve a certificates file.
     *
     * @param string $url location
     * @return array certificates
     */
    private function retrieveCertsFromLocation($url)
    {
        if (!$file = file_get_contents($url)) {
            throw new Exception(
                "Failed to retrieve verification certificates: '" .
                $url . "'."
            );
        }

        return json_decode($file, true);
    }

    // Gets federated sign-on certificates to use for verifying identity tokens.
    // Returns certs as array structure, where keys are key ids, and values
    // are PEM encoded certificates.
    private function getFederatedSignOnCerts()
    {
        $certs = $this->retrieveCertsFromLocation(
            self::FEDERATED_SIGNON_CERT_URL
        );

        if (!isset($certs['keys'])) {
            throw new Exception(
                'federated sign-on certs expects "keys" to be set'
            );
        }

        return $certs['keys'];
    }

    private function getJwtService()
    {
        $jwtClass = 'JWT';
        if (class_exists('\Firebase\JWT\JWT')) {
            $jwtClass = 'Firebase\JWT\JWT';
        }

        return new $jwtClass();
    }

    private function getPublicKey($cert)
    {
        $modulus = $this->jwt->urlsafeB64Decode($cert['n']);
        $exponent = $this->jwt->urlsafeB64Decode($cert['e']);
        $component = ['n' => $modulus, 'e' => $exponent];

        if (class_exists('phpseclib3\Crypt\RSA\PublicKey')) {
            /** @var PublicKey $loader */
            $loader = PublicKeyLoader::load($component);

            return $loader->toString('PKCS8');
        }

        $rsaClass = $this->getRsaClass();
        $rsa = new $rsaClass();
        $rsa->loadKey($component);

        return $rsa->getPublicKey();
    }

    private function getRsaClass()
    {
        if (class_exists('phpseclib3\Crypt\RSA')) {
            return 'phpseclib3\Crypt\RSA';
        }

        if (class_exists('phpseclib\Crypt\RSA')) {
            return 'phpseclib\Crypt\RSA';
        }

        return 'Crypt_RSA';
    }

    private function getOpenSslConstant()
    {
        if (class_exists('phpseclib3\Crypt\AES')) {
            return 'phpseclib3\Crypt\AES::ENGINE_OPENSSL';
        }

        if (class_exists('phpseclib\Crypt\RSA')) {
            return 'phpseclib\Crypt\RSA::MODE_OPENSSL';
        }

        if (class_exists('Crypt_RSA')) {
            return 'CRYPT_RSA_MODE_OPENSSL';
        }

        throw new Exception('Cannot find RSA class');
    }

    /**
   * phpseclib calls "phpinfo" by default, which requires special
   * whitelisting in the AppEngine VM environment. This function
   * sets constants to bypass the need for phpseclib to check phpinfo
   *
   * @see phpseclib/Math/BigInteger
   * @see https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-php/issues/85
   */
    private function setPhpsecConstants()
    {
        if (filter_var(getenv('GAE_VM'), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN)) {
            if (!defined('MATH_BIGINTEGER_OPENSSL_ENABLED')) {
                define('MATH_BIGINTEGER_OPENSSL_ENABLED', true);
            }
            if (!defined('CRYPT_RSA_MODE')) {
                define('CRYPT_RSA_MODE', constant($this->getOpenSslConstant()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you just guessing that this many files will be a problem, or have you actually received an error?

Comment: @AlexHowansky I'm not guessing. Using all 20,000 files that composer loads, it works normally without any errors. But it occupies almost all the space of "inodes" that my hosting allows. And of those 20,000 files, I think I would only need a maximum of 3 or 4 to do what I want to work. So my question is how to make all this lighter.

Comment: A hard cap of 20K inodes is nonsensical, find another host. The empty skeleton Symfony app has 10K just by itself, and you'll never be able to get anywhere near node or have a file-based cache. You could hand-write the auth but then you'll just run into the same problem on the next library you try to import.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Yes, but this is a future problem, currently I just want to know what would be the best way to do a google authenticator JWT verification, without needing 20 thousand files, knowing that I could do the same thing with much less . That's all I wanted to know. That's why I asked a question based on that and not whether I'm going to have problems with future libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

([similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66820938) has some more details too)

for no services at all (for instance you're only using the API to [verify the integrity of a JWT ID token](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth#using-a-google-api-client-library)) the `extra.google/apiclient-services` array/list in `composer.json` needs to contain an empty string

```
{
    "require": {
        "google/apiclient": "^2.12.1"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "pre-autoload-dump": "Google\\Task\\Composer::cleanup"
    },
    "extra": {
        "google/apiclient-services": [ "" ]
    }
}
```

before running

```
$ composer update
```

– That clears up ~20000 files

(general task described at [Google API client README](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/main/README.md#cleaning-up-unused-services))

Comment: It was exactly what I needed. I had found this solution in the google documentation with the google/apiclient-services line, but I had left only youtube to greatly reduce the amount of files, but now with your answer it helped me to understand that an empty array can also be used, and so I can remove youtube as well. Perfect, thank you very much for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP client for Google, there are almost 20,000 files and more than 50 Megabytes. Just monstrous, if you just want to validate a user.
Use one of these access points.

- https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?access_token=XXXXX
- https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token=XXXXX
- https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?access_token=XXXX

```
$token=$_POST['id_token'];
$response = file_get_contents ( "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token=$token" );
    
$response = json_decode ( $response );
$response =  (array)$response;
$name = $response['name'];
$fpic = $response['picture'];
$email = $response['email'];
```

If all goes well, the result of $response will be an array with the user's basic information.

Then you can add the user to the database, set cookies, etc.

This way of doing it, does not need Guzzle, no Google PHP SDK, no JWT.

**It's only 10 lines of code. Very simple.**